# Replace ][ in a JSON string

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have the following JSON string

```
[{
    "email": "first@gmail.com",
    "createdate": "2016-03-24 08:16:52",
    "from_email": null,
    "from_liked_pageid": null,
    "source": "direct",
    "bonus_entry_url": "\/qbxttt\/h1ryd2",
    "entry_url": "https:\/\/admin.woobox.com\/manage\/offers\/entries\/20160909-1\/nLbCpFW0ojJaSNdgFcfMqkCvmjeSUbirdYguz%2F2Ya4O5xalcyrAvKb7MCR71frLSepDTRVcYBMkJ6C7tqotSzQ%3D%3D",
    "shareurl": "http:\/\/woobox.com\/qbxttt\/h1ryd2",
    "picked": "0",
    "actionbutton": "",
    "custom_3_first": "first",
    "custom_3_last": "first",
    "custom_4": "7176585018",
    "fullname": "first first",
    "id": "qbxttt"
}, {
    "email": "second@gmail.com",
    "createdate": "2016-03-24 08:17:01",
    "from_email": null,
    "from_liked_pageid": null,
    "source": "direct",
    "bonus_entry_url": "\/qbxttt\/h1rygc",
    "entry_url": "https:\/\/admin.woobox.com\/manage\/offers\/entries\/20160909-1\/Tmg5lBCuKn87OCSHUBHvbcNHX610SbdOoAuHVqkJI1GpszeBwpL9%2BFrQf06SD8S25LzQq0uy21EFyZyjglPM2A%3D%3D",
    "shareurl": "http:\/\/woobox.com\/qbxttt\/h1rygc",
    "picked": "0",
    "actionbutton": "",
    "custom_3_first": "second",
    "custom_3_last": "second",
    "custom_4": "7176585011",
    "fullname": "second second",
    "id": "qbxttt"
}, {
    "email": "third@gmail.com",
    "createdate": "2016-03-24 08:17:33",
    "from_email": null,
    "from_liked_pageid": null,
    "source": "direct",
    "bonus_entry_url": "\/qbxttt\/h1ryin",
    "entry_url": "https:\/\/admin.woobox.com\/manage\/offers\/entries\/20160909-1\/kD5srK7WdnOcu2EAw7DEOc8VE7rVRMDgkJc8UQqxnzh9oqDBm%2BNb%2Bp9%2BlpcvXPO6hy9Srg3SXyvZM%2FaXpMA1Uw%3D%3D",
    "shareurl": "http:\/\/woobox.com\/qbxttt\/h1ryin",
    "picked": "0",
    "actionbutton": "",
    "custom_3_first": "third",
    "custom_3_last": "third",
    "custom_4": "7176585104",
    "fullname": "third third",
    "id": "qbxttt"
}][{
    "email": "conference.room@gmail.com",
    "createdate": "2016-03-24 08:29:10",
    "from_email": null,
    "from_liked_pageid": null,
    "source": "direct",
    "bonus_entry_url": "\/qbxttt\/h1s15g",
    "entry_url": "https:\/\/admin.woobox.com\/manage\/offers\/entries\/20160909-1\/V5%2FvZ8XE197qahQoJVi%2FAha5toMAAz19mAl%2FowX6NsoqGmDMJiV3adHQfPcJrU3WxQ6NagWZ8xh%2FZexXCEMyBg%3D%3D",
    "shareurl": "http:\/\/woobox.com\/qbxttt\/h1s15g",
    "picked": "0",
    "actionbutton": "",
    "custom_3_first": "conference",
    "custom_3_last": "conference",
    "custom_4": "9195583344",
    "fullname": "conference conference",
    "id": "qbxttt"
}, {
    "email": "sally.huang@gmail.com",
    "createdate": "2016-03-24 08:31:48",
    "from_email": null,
    "from_liked_pageid": null,
    "source": "direct",
    "bonus_entry_url": "\/qbxttt\/h1s1xa",
    "entry_url": "https:\/\/admin.woobox.com\/manage\/offers\/entries\/20160909-1\/Fex6pkK3YFSBT%2F%2FD37bvV1ik5Gum3tDOMuYsQwNz%2FVWjNTyLMd%2BJI3E%2FZnUcrshAIhE62UbCHPwoncQ5NYPYUg%3D%3D",
    "shareurl": "http:\/\/woobox.com\/qbxttt\/h1s1xa",
    "picked": "0",
    "actionbutton": "",
    "custom_3_first": "sally",
    "custom_3_last": "huang",
    "custom_4": "2153342222",
    "fullname": "sally huang",
    "id": "qbxttt"
}][{
    "email": "test.gmail@gmail.com",
    "createdate": "2016-03-24 08:36:01",
    "from_email": null,
    "from_liked_pageid": null,
    "source": "direct",
    "bonus_entry_url": "\/qbxttt\/h1s2ql",
    "entry_url": "https:\/\/admin.woobox.com\/manage\/offers\/entries\/20160909-1\/bop12HUD0vcV339mAB4RkEg%2BiYj6oDB%2B2NDK7auwwPLdqzWx8Jh4ppj%2BhRt2VDOpE1hrZ7y0yjj65qLdynoCwg%3D%3D",
    "shareurl": "http:\/\/woobox.com\/qbxttt\/h1s2ql",
    "picked": "0",
    "actionbutton": "",
    "custom_3_first": "test",
    "custom_3_last": "gmail",
    "custom_4": "2152931118",
    "fullname": "test gmail",
    "id": "qbxttt"
}][{
    "email": "sixth.test@mgmgrand.com",
    "createdate": "2016-03-24 09:02:07",
    "from_email": null,
    "from_liked_pageid": null,
    "source": "direct",
    "bonus_entry_url": "\/qbxttt\/h1s8da",
    "entry_url": "https:\/\/admin.woobox.com\/manage\/offers\/entries\/20160909-1\/olKS0uHVdNb%2Fv9EkNHiXGlPVZVgVZ1r9UqmrHZYxLi33muihmcf3NkjMC59lh6jkM%2F9C5moj4t%2BupGHwtF384w%3D%3D",
    "shareurl": "http:\/\/woobox.com\/qbxttt\/h1s8da",
    "picked": "0",
    "actionbutton": "",
    "custom_3_first": "sixth",
    "custom_3_last": "sixth",
    "custom_4": "2151112333",
    "fullname": "sixth sixth",
    "id": "qbxttt"
}]
```

The JSON string is decoded from a .txt file and unfortunately depending on the time data gets posted to the .txt file, it will create a new bracket `][` causing the whole string to be invalid.

I am trying to replace the brackets `][` not from the beginning or end of the string but anytime it occurs in the middle. See lines 41, 89, 97. Any ideas on how I can do a string replace?

```
$url = 'http://www.mywebsite.com/sweeps/test.txt';
$content = file_get_contents($url);    
$tmp = explode('][', $content);
foreach ($tmp as $json_part) {
$user = json_decode('['.rtrim(ltrim($json_string, '['), ']').']', true);
$result = $wrap->add(array(
    'EmailAddress' => $user->email,
    'Name' => $user->fullname,
'Resubscribe' => true

));
}
```

Comment: `$content = str_replace('][','', $content);`

Comment: what about just `str_replace('][', ',', $content)`?

Comment: @pr0metheus, brackets must be replaced with comma in order to keep valid JSON.

Comment: @mitkosoft I should replace the explode with str_replace?

Comment: @mitkosoft yes you have absolute right

Comment: @chronotrigga, no, just make `$content = str_replace('][', ',', $content)` after `file_get_contents`. this will produce valid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace:

```
$user = json_decode('['.rtrim(ltrim($json_string, '['), ']').']', true);
```

with

```
$json_string = str_replace('][', ',', $json_string);
$user = json_decode($json_string);
```